# Jquery/php output custom error messagge

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, error-handling

I have an Ajax autocomplete box on an input field of a form. In jquery, I have the following ajax settings

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myUrl,
    data: $("#id__form").serialize(),
    success: function(data){
                  alert("do something");
              },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) { 
                  alert(xhr.status+ " "+ thrownError+ " " + textStatus);
              },
   dataType: "json"
    });
```

On the server side, I have this php code

```
  $data = array('type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error: '.$text);
    header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    die(json_encode($data));
```

All works fine both in case of success and in case of error. However, I didn't figure out how do I access from jquery the text I defined in php as $text

xhr.status is 400, textStatus is "error" and thrownError is "Bad Request", but no signs of what I defined as $text

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, thanks to this article http://wingkaiwan.com/2012/10/21/deserialize-error-in-json-for-jquery-ajax/

The problem was that the variable data in the success callback handles automatically json, but I had to parse it in the error callback. This works:

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        var error = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        alert(error.message);               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you echo the $text variable in your file you can get to it from your javascript file.

php code:

```
     echo $text;
```

change to javascript:

```
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
    url: myUrl,
      data: $("#id__form").serialize(),
     success: function(data){

              //do something with the data returned from php file
              alert(data);//<---change to javascript code


          },
         error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) { 
              alert(xhr.status+ " "+ thrownError+ " " + textStatus);
          },
       dataType: "json"
        });
```

Comment: if you use "echo" in your php, you can't send your request as json. If you do so, use dataType: "" in your request

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax post you defined a json call. In your php backend you defined a array, so you can access these params by key. Your array:

```
<?php 
    $arr = array();
    $arr['message'] = 'What you like?';
    $arr['errorCode'] = '12345';

    die(json_encode($arr));
?>
```

In your case you will have access the data argument by adding the key, like **data.message**:

**success: function(data){ alert(data.message); }**

So, it have to look like that:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: myUrl,
     data: $("#id__form").serialize(),
     success: function(data){
          alert(data.message+' '+data.errorCode);
          $('#someDivTag').html(data.message);
     },
     dataType: "json"
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I access the data variable from the error function? I figured out I can use xhr.responseText, but that still does not handle the json data as expected